# How to add conditional mount_uploader using carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

Suppose i have a model `CustomMetric` (EAV type) having fields `label,value,data_type` of type String and data_type can be one of the following String

```
"Text","Decimal","Percentage","Range","Date","Image","Document"
```

Now i want to check first if data_type is Image then mount the uploader else not.

like =>

```
class CustomMetric < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :value, ImageUploader, if: :is_image_type?

    def is_image_type?
        self.data_type == "Image"   
    end
end
```

However above code is not working. It mounts on value without checking the condition.

Is there any way to do this.? Is it possible with carrierwave..? Any alternative?

Comment: Do want to have your filefield changed in your view too?

Comment: i have filefield for Image data_type in the view.

Comment: Yes, but do you want it to change based on the condition?

Comment: i have already done that..now i want to check on server side before saving using carrierwave file uploader.

Comment: You  cannot do it by conditional `mount_uploader` is class method and instance know nothing about class methods. You should use `STI` and implement different model for type.

Comment: @Зелёный thanks, if i use STI i have to add type in CustomMetric,can i use my own data_type in place of type to identify submodel.

Comment: read about `STI` this right direction for your case.

Comment: @Зелёный found self.inheritance_column = :data_type. now m switiching to STI. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The use case above can be solved with Single Table Inheritance and as CarrierWave v1.1.0 there is still no conditional mount. But...

Note that `mount_uploader` first [includes a module](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/v1.1.0/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb#L138) in the class and then [overrides](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/v1.1.0/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb#L363) the original `value=` to call the method `value=` [defined](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/v1.1.0/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb#L145) in the included module. So, a workaround is just to redefine the accessors **after** you have called `mount_uploader`:

```
class CustomMetric < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :value, ImageUploader

    def value=(arg)
        if is_image_type?
            super
        else
            write_attribute(:value, arg)
        end
    end

    def value
        # some logic here
    end

    def is_image_type?
        self.data_type == "Image"   
    end
end
```